# Пагинация для таблицы

Tags: pagination, javascript

Пытаюсь разобраться с пагинацией для таблицы
http://jsfiddle.net/5HA8g/

Кнопки вперед и назад работают, но не получается привести к нормальному виду номера страниц. Использую bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination

Может кто помочь, что еще не доделал?

Comment: `<span>` тоже надо в `<li>` оборачивать. Портянки у вас там безумные, конечно.

Comment: @Fike вы наверное про эту строчку

<span class="page-number"></span>

мучил её очень долго, не понимаю как изменить

пробывал и так и много раз по другому
<li class="activ"></li>

но не работает, не нашел правильно варианта

Comment: @Колямбий

1. Проб**о**вал
2. Я же написал, что нужно оборачивать в `<li>`, тут сложно понять двусмысленно. [фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/5HA8g/1/).

Comment: @Fike спасибо за помощь, понял в этом месте свою ошибку, но пока бросил этим заниматься, буду другие вещи реализовывать учиться